# Problems when uploaded website onto the server

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image of the Navigation background went missing when I upload my website to the server. Everything else works fine. What can be wrong here?

```
navbar-default {

background: url(img/meshH.png);
padding: 10px 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
font-weight: 500;
padding-bottom: 18px;
```

Comment: Did you upload `meshH.png` into the directory `img`?

Comment: What happens when you directly access that image from browser?

Comment: What is the url of the website?

Comment: Check the permissions on the image

Answer (score 1):

May be the problem is with image path, better to give the path by adding ../ at beginning. It means the current folder then add the image path.

like `background: url(../img/meshH.png);`

or

```
background-image: url('img/meshH.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

'img' folder should be at the root of your virtual directory, say the web site name is MyWebSite and it's physically pointing to C:\MyWebSite, so 'img' folder should be C:\MyWebSite\img.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSS file is located in a directory in your root folder, you might have to append  `../` to the url in order to target the img folder properly like so:

```
background: url(../img/meshH.png);
```

Or

```
background-image: url(../img/meshH.png);
```

The path starts in your CSS directory, so you need to go up one folder.